# ant run app , the command dosnt get forked

Tags: java, ant

i start my app from ant , but when it started via command cmd command line .
its just got running in the foreground and doesn't continue to the next target.
how can i execute the app and then test it with junit task via ant ?

```
<target name="init" depends="compile,run,test" description="init build ">
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="build_dirs"
        description="compile the source " >
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" verbose="${TALK}" includeantruntime="false" >

        <classpath refid="class.path" />
    </javac>    
  </target>


<target name="run">

        <java classname="${main-class}" fork="true">    
            <env key="LD_LIBRARY_PATH" value="${libs_java_library_path}:${env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"/>       

             <classpath>                
               <pathelement location="../lib/misc/log4j.jar"/>             
               <pathelement path="conf"/>
               <pathelement path="dist/lib"/>
             </classpath>             
        </java>
</target>


<target name="test"  >
    <junit printsummary="no" showoutput="true">
      <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>      
      <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
      <test name="com.controller.core.workflowShouldHaveValidXML" />          
    </junit>
  </target>
```

the test target never executed , why ?

Comment: you should be able to run it in the background with `spawn="true"` but I have to admit I have no idea how to stop it after the tests have run.

Comment: well i try it and no it still the same ....